# Quitting method chain execution early

Tags: ruby, refactoring

Here's some simple Ruby code:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(args)
    @data = args[:data]
  end

  def perform
    quit_if_no_data
    print_message
  end

  def quit_if_no_data
    return unless @data
  end

  def print_message
    puts "You've got the data, congrats!"
  end
end


Foo.new({}).perform # want nil to be returned
```

How do I quit from the method chain execution with nil returned if the object is instantiated without data? I'd like `Foo.new({}).perform` to return `nil`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not necessary, or desired, that you prepend or append your tags to the title of your question. If you can work them into the title with a normal sentence then it's OK to use them, otherwise rely on the tags. Also, just as an OO hint, a class should be a "something", a noun or object, not a verb. Methods are verbs usually, so your class should be "Something". It'll help make your code more readable as you progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation you probably want to raise an exception in the constructor if a required argument isn't supplied.

If the argument is actually optional, you need to slightly rethink how you're structuring you program. You should drop the `quit_if_` prefix, that's never going to work, and its not *supposed* to work. You can't invent new forms of program flow that way. There is no way you can (or should) be able to jump out of a method that way. If you want to, you need to be more explicit with a `raise` or `throw` and a `rescue`/`catch`.

The way to do this properly is for your `quit_if_no_data` method to actually be called `should_quit?` and simply return true/false, indicating whether you should quit, and then conditionally quit from the calling method:

```
  def perform
    return if should_quit?
    print_message
  end

  def should_quit?
    @data == nil
  end
```

Because Ruby is *Ruby*, you can make something that works similarly to what you're trying to do with a proc, but it's an extremely overwrought solution to your problem, so **don't do this**:

```
 def perform
   with_data do
     print_message
   end
 end

 def with_data
   yield if @data
 end
```

Comment: Thanks @meagar, I overlooked the "boolean" functions.